# User-defined functions in another CMakeLists.txt file in CLion

Tags: cmake, clion

I want to separate my user-defined functions from the main `CmakeLists.txt` so they are not in the way of my stuff.

I work in CLion primarily and want to have syntax highlight and code completion, which CLion provides for CMake.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you add another file alongside with your main `CMakeLists.txt` and name it something like: `myfunctions.cmake`.

`*.cmake` extension is recognized by CLion and enables CMake syntax highlight and code completion.

Then in your `CMakeLists.txt` you add line:
`include(myfunctions.cmake)`

Now you can use your user-defined functions in your main and all derived (from add_subdirectory) `CMakeLists.txt` files. Also you'll get CLion code completion for your user-defined functions as well (it works in CLion 2020.1, but I don't know about older versions)